# How do I know when all asynchronous Operations from a For Loop are finished?

Tags: java, gwt

I have a for loop over a list:

```
boolean initialized = false
for(final Share share : shares) {

    someInstance.check(new someCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            // do something
        }
    });         
}
initialized = true;
```

In each step a asynchronous operation is performed which is called check(). I want to set the initialized = true when all check() operations are completed. 
Is there a way I can do this in Java/GWT?

**How do I know when all asynchronous Operations from a For Loop are finished?**

Comment: Is `someCallback` an interface or a class? If a class, you coulf add a static boolean method `processedAll()` or something, along with a static `someCallback[]`. The method loops through the array, checking to make sure each one is finished. There are actually a few ways to do this. It would be nice to know if `someCallback` was a class or interface

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each time `onSuccess` is called, just increase some shared counter which counts how many have finished. You know how many you have started (say N) so once `the finished counter` reaches the same value (N) you know that they are all finished. Then the last one which finishes will set `initialized = true`.

Comment: Or count down to 0, that way nothing has to know a magic number except the place that initialized the counter.

Comment: @zapl Yes, that would be even better.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if GWT has any special restrictions, but you could wait until they've all succeeded for example using a simple `CountDownLatch`

```
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(shares.size());
    for(final Share share : shares) {
        someInstance.check(new someCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess() {
                latch.countDown();
                // do something
            }
        });         
    }
    latch.await();
    boolean initalized = true;
```

That would simply block execution until each callback has counted down once. Blocking is usually a bad idea though. So you might want to set `initialized` ansynchronously as well. and use some callback once it's true.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this callback counter implementation. It fires provided AsyncCallback when all callbacks are finished. Something similar to Promise.all(). This implementation has lock and unlock methods to be sure that some of the callbacks is not countering it until necessary.

This is how to use it:

```
CallbackCounter counter = new CallbackCounter(yourFinalCallback);
//counter.lock(); call this if methodWithCallback may execute callback synchronously
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    AsyncCallback<Void> counterCallback = counter.async();
    methodWithCallback(i, counterCallback);
}
//counter.unlock();
```

This is CallbackCounter class:

```
public class CallbackCounter
{

    private int count;
    private int maxCount;
    private boolean failOnError;
    private Throwable exceptionDuringLock;

    private boolean unlocked;
    private AsyncCallback<Void> callback;

    public CallbackCounter(AsyncCallback<Void> callback)
    {
        this(true, callback);
    }

    public CallbackCounter(boolean failOnError, AsyncCallback<Void> callback)
    {
        this.failOnError = failOnError;
        this.callback = callback;

        count = 0;
        maxCount = 0;
        unlocked = true;
    }

    public int getCount()
    {
        return maxCount;
    }

    public LocalDatabaseRemoveCallback localDatabaseRemove()
    {
        maxCount++;

        return new LocalDatabaseRemoveCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onRemove(String key)
            {
                counterSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(String key, Throwable error)
            {
                counterFail(error);
            }
        };
    }

    public AsyncCallback<Void> async()
    {
        maxCount++;

        return new AsyncCallback<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void result)
            {
                counterSuccess();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Throwable caught)
            {
                counterFail(caught);
            }
        };
    }

    public CommandCallback<Void> command()
    {
        maxCount++;

        return new CommandCallback<Void>()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCallback(Void data)
            {
                counterSuccess();
            }
        };
    }

    public SimpleCallback simple()
    {
        maxCount++;

        return new SimpleCallback()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCallback()
            {
                counterSuccess();
            }
        };
    }

    public void lock()
    {
        if (unlocked)
        {
            unlocked = false;
        }
    }

    public void unlock()
    {
        if (!unlocked)
        {
            unlocked = true;

            if (count >= maxCount)
            {
                if (exceptionDuringLock == null)
                {
                    conterSuccessCallback();
                }
                else
                {
                    Throwable e = exceptionDuringLock;
                    exceptionDuringLock = null;

                    conterFailCallback(e);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void counterSuccess()
    {
        count++;

        if (!unlocked)
        {
            return;
        }

        if (count >= maxCount)
        {
            conterSuccessCallback();
        }
    }

    private void conterSuccessCallback()
    {
        if (callback != null)
        {
            AsyncCallback<Void> callbackToCall = callback;
            callback = null;

            callbackToCall.onSuccess(null);
        }
    }

    private void counterFail(Throwable caught)
    {
        count++;

        if (failOnError)
        {
            if (unlocked)
            {
                conterFailCallback(caught);
            }
            else
            {
                exceptionDuringLock = caught;
            }
        }
    }

    private void conterFailCallback(Throwable caught)
    {
        if (callback != null)
        {
            AsyncCallback<Void> callbackToCall = callback;
            callback = null;

            callbackToCall.onFailure(caught);
        }
    }
}
```